# MySQL is it good to store 1MB of JSON

Tags: mysql, json

So i have a user based application, which multiple (around 500 users in total) users will be accessing.

Every user will have like 500KB of encoded JSON string in each column (total of 10 cols) that makes 5MB of data for each user.

For 500 users this will be 5*500MB of data in total.

I won't be doing any filtering and searching in the JSON. Moreover the data will be totally different across all the JSONs, so i can not think of storing only the unique content.

I can not use No SQL Databases. Is this a good architecture, if yes what should be the column type?

Comment: It's definitely worth thinking about splitting the JSON string into "native", normalized database data if possible, and generating the JSON on request, in case you ever want to run database-type operations on it (filtering, searching, ordering...)

Comment: @Pekka웃 i won't be doing any filtering and searching in the JSON. Moreover the data will be totally different across all the JSONs, so i can not think of storing only the unique content.

Comment: Ah, ok. I guess what I'd do is Google `mysql large blobs performance`, it yields things like http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database

Comment: How about: you store that json into a file and save file's reference in mysql.

Comment: Look into mysql 5.7 (for other users that follow, not necessarily this OP) for its json support. Otherwise, sounds like intermittent use of not that many users for it to be treated with much concern (read: blob)

Answer (score 1):

You may try using mysql 5.7+ and `JSON` column type, internally it will be stored more efficiently and also you can query it.